# Styling of MUI Typography is overriding Link component default styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Why is the `Typography` component from MUI overriding the styling of my `Link` component also from MUI? It's overriding and removed the default colour and `cursor: pointer` of the Link's properties. Is there a way to remove this behaviour from the `Typography` component and retain the default properties of `Link`?

Here's a sample code:

```
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from '@mui/material';


<Typography>
  Some text&nbsp;
  <Link> a link </Link>
</Typography>
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa0Br.png

Asides from adding a class to Link with the following properties which should already be achieved by the default properties of `Link`... :

```
cursor: pointer;
color: 'primary';
```

is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Have you checked the styling of the Typography and the Link in your theme? Either the styling there or the styling from a styled-component seems to overriding your `Link`. Have a look at this simple example, you will notice that the `Link` style has only been affected for the default `font-family` https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-drake-tvrudn?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Oh wow interesting.. You're right, my theme was overriding the styling of `Typography`. Thanks for that